# winapi: Which driver will be used for my USB device (which may not be connected)?

Tags: windows, usb

For collecting diagnostic information, I'd like to include which driver will be used for a particular device, even if the device is not connected.

Relevant Driver details would be Provider and Version.
For the device, Vendor ID and Product ID are known.

The driver is preinstalled, but no device of that type may have been connected before.

---

[edit] The purpose is troubleshooting installation issues. Normally, drivers get preinstalled with the software installation.

However, one 3rd party driver installation is particulary susceptible to get uninstalled due to bad UX that I can't control, and some customers go "creative" when trying to fix something, with some customers the language barrier is too high. I just want support to see reliably "oh, they have an old driver installed, for whatever reason.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want run a diagnostic program on a user's computer which will tell you some information about what driver will be used for the device and you want this to work when the device is not plugged in?  And the purpose of this is to troubleshoot any problems the user might have with the device?

Comment: Yes, it's for diagnostics - I've updated the quesiotn with details

Answer (score -1):

I think you should investigate the registry keys in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB`.  In general, every distinct USB device that was previously plugged into the computer will have an entry there.  The entries have a "Driver" entry with a GUID and you can probably figure out what that GUID means by searching for it in other parts of the registry.

If the device has never plugged in, then you would probably want to use Microsoft's devcon utility (which is open source) to list all the installed OEM driver packages (INF files).  You can then open the INF files, read them, and see if they might apply to your device.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I still think Microsoft's devcon utility (which is open source) is a good place to start for inspecting the driver packages on a system and the registry is a good place to see what driver is really used.